# functions in $\mathbb{C}[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4]$ that vanish for all $(u^3, u^2v, uv^2, v^3)$ where $u,v \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to show that $Z =\{(u^3, u^2v, uv^2, v^3) \mid  u,v \in \mathbb{C}\}$ is an algebraic set.
So I need functions in $\mathbb{C}[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4]$ that vanish for all $(u^3, u^2v, uv^2, v^3)$ where $u,v \in \mathbb{C}$.

I already found out that the function $f_{uv}(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = -x_1 - 3x_2 - 3x_3 - x_4 + (u+v)^3$ vanishes at $(u^3, u^2v, uv^2, v^3)$. But how can I find one that vanishes for all complex numbers $u$, $v$?

Comment: You need $x_1x_3-x_2^2=0$ and $x_2x_4-x_3^2=0$. Do these suffice?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown    Great, thanks! I would like to find $I(Z)$ as well, so I need either all such functions or the Ideal generated by $x_1x_3−x_2^2=0$ and $x_2x_4−x_2^3=0$ (to apply Hilbert's Nullstellensatz) right? Could you help me with this as well?